# "con carga" vs. "en carga"

Tags: significado-en-contexto

quisiera saber el significado de “en carga” en “[radiografías anteroposterior de rodillas en carga y lateral de la rodilla izquierda](https://doctorlopezcapape.com/cirugia-ortopedica/artrosis-de-rodilla-gonartrosis)”. ¿Significa algo como “cosa que hace peso sobre otra (RAE)” o “peso que soporta una estructura (RAE)”? Y quisiera preguntar si existe alguna diferencia de significado entre “de carga” y “en carga” en este contexto. ¡Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: No veo cómo una rodilla pueda hacer peso sobre otra cosa; pero soportar peso, sí, por supuesto.

Comment: Carga en medicina no se usa como un termino especifico cuando uno esta haciendo uso del musculo/hueso?

Comment: Una articulación "*en* carga" ha de ser aquella que esté soportando un peso/una fuerza, mientras que una articulación "*de* carga" es una cuya función es soportar peso, verbigracia, la rodilla.